# В методе АОА угол прихода измеряет мобильное устройство или точки доступов?

Tags: wifi, геолокация

В методе AOA  угол прихода измеряет мобильное устройство или точки доступов (AP) измеряют  и возвращают значение к мобильному устройству ?

Comment: через АП. есть доступ к мумимо точке? давай посмотрим что драйвер отдает

Comment: Мне  нужно   найти местоположение пользователей которые используют приложение . у нас нет заранее приготовленной инфраструктуры и мы можем использовать лишь существующую инфраструктуру которая будет под рукой то есть точки доступов WI FI (например которые данный момент доступны у пользователя).

Comment: тогда aoa сразу пролетает =) пробуй триангуляцию по мощности, но точность от неё будет никакущая.

Comment: а ещё у вас проблема с доступом на устройстве к местоположению будет. Андроид например с пятой версии не дает узнать мак адрес. Вязать по ип